# Angular - use custom preloadingStrategy in forChild routes

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have app-routing.module with one lazy loaded module which loaded dashbord.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
{ path: 'dir', 
  loadChildren: './dboard/dboard.module#DboardModule'}, 
{ path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent }
```

In dashBoardRouting I have other lazy loaded modules:

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {  path: '', component: DboardComponent,
        children: [             
        { path: 'accounter', 
          loadChildren: './accounter/accounter.module#AccounterModule' },
        { path: 'manager', 
          loadChildren: './maanger/manager.module#ManagerModule' },
         ...
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

AccounterModule and other lazy loaded modules have their own routing modules.

I want to use custom preloading strategy in forChild method is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

preloadingStrategy is only defined on the root level , and it will automatically be applied for all rooting modules with .ForChild().

so you should have a custom preloadingStrategy function that can handle all routes on all levels

Comment: In my case it is not happening.

Comment: can you please add the full routing model that you have implemented

Comment: As given in angular documentation of custom pre-loading strategy, apply data: {preload:true} to the routes which you want to preload.

Comment: If forRoot has a lazily loaded module which has other child lazily loaded modules then to pre-load child lazily loaded module, you have to apply **data: {preload:true}**  to both parent lazily loaded module and child lazily loaded module

Comment: Has there been any fixes? I've searched a lot and this was the only thread close to my issue. Lazy loaded module in child routes aren't being loaded with [`QuicklinkStrategy`](https://github.com/mgechev/ngx-quicklink) and with `data: {preload:true}`, can confirm that it did work when there were fewer modules

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you should create your own preload strategy as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20912).